# Replace values in input filed Jquery?

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I have some phone input to remove empty spaces

```
 $('#phone').val($('#phone').val().replace(/ +?/g, ''));
```

But sometimes problem value can be like this

**+65555-555-555 555555**

What i need is to remove all white spaces,and also remove -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#phone').val($('#phone').val().replace(/[ -]/g, ''));
```

This should be enough for your cause.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/14

Comment: @BhojendraSah `+?` is not needed.`\s` covers newlines as well.`\s`=`[\r\n\t\f ]`.